# Проблема с запуском openserver

Tags: openserver

Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует libhttpd.dll. Попробуйте переустановить заново.

2-й раз переустанавливал, ничего не работает.
Как можно решить?

Comment: Какая ось. Если в рамках требований openserver, то смотрите проблемы с осью - вирус, повреждение и т.д. Конечно, запускать с правами администратора.

Comment: Вирусов нету, повреждений нету, запуск с правами Администратора есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема у Вас с осью и недоустановленными программами, скорее всего - если вирусов и повреждений действительно нет.

*На время установки можно бы отключить антивир и прочую защиту

Посмотрите еще раз:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

+

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

=> [Мануал OSPanel](https://ospanel.io/docs/#ustanovka)

Comment: Спасибо бро, Выручил. Ошибка оказалась в отсутствии Microsoft Visual C++ который был, но пропал(Переустановил).

Comment: )Пожалуйста, рад!